# Django deployment tools

Tags: django, deployment, release-management

I'm looking for some tool (or set of tools) that could help me automate deploying Django projects with all required dependencies.

I googled for some solutions but I am curious what are your favorite ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll second meder's suggestion: user virtualenv + pip. These will give isolated environments that can be mantained and replicated easily.

Once you got that running, you have two choices:

- [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/): Is great for simpler setups. You can script many deploy situations (code checkout, multiple servers, etc). Fabric makes little assumptions on what and how you are deploying, so it's pretty flexible.
- [Zope's buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/docs/tutorial.html) : is more complex and harder to setup, but can do pretty much any deploy scenario you throw at it.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [silver-lining](http://cloudsilverlining.org/). It's a bit early-on, but seems okay, as long as you are doing everything the same way in your project.

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same way. I would love to move to this type of deployment, but I can't really change the deployment system of my current project to this right now.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel can you update the  link for silver-lining. I tried to google but nothing turned up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like pip requirements?

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/